# RewriteRule Form Get Request

Tags: mod-rewrite

When i submit my form this is my url:

```
index.php?pagina=search&terms=soccer
```

I want to change it to:

```
/pagina/search/terms/soccer
```

what I have so far doesn't work

```
#searchRewriteRules
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^terms=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /pagina/search/terms/%1? [R=301]
```

Could somebody help me

Answer (score 0):

Your query string is `pagina=search&terms=soccer`. You need to match that completely. Please note that if you are doing a POST request you loose the POST body on the redirect. Besides that you need to translate the pretty url back to the normal url, and prevent an infinite redirect from happening.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php?pagina=search&terms=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /pagina/search/terms/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^pagina/search/terms/(.*)$ /index.php?pagina=search&terms=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

it's working with jquery.
I have created a new page called rewritesearch.php and inserted into my main page where the form is.

**rewritesearch.php**

```
// Base Url
$url = BASE_URL;

echo <<<EOT
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submit').click(function() {
                 // get the terms value
                 var terms = $('.search').val();

                 goUrl = '{$url}pagina/search/terms/'+terms+'/';
                 window.location = goUrl;
                 return false;  // Prevent the default button behaviour
            });
            $('#search_form').submit( function() {
                 return false;  // May be necessary to prevent the default form behaviour
            });
      });
 </script>
EOT;
```